# Windows: How to convert binary database file (compressed with zlib) to human-readable string data? (ProcrastiTracker .PT file)

Tags: compression, conversion, c++, c, binary-files

The current question is derived directly from [this one](https://superuser.com/q/1677398/1539268), as my general problem is how to process the data collected by the [ProcrastiTracker](https://strlen.com/procrastitracker/) program. Once installed on a Windows machine, ProcrastiTracker runs in the background and tracks screen time usage by monitoring active windows.

Although the program has a built-in GUI interface that enables the user to analyze the data collected, it is still limited. I would like to use the "raw" data and process it the way I want.

Unfortunately, [the program saves its database files as binary files](https://github.com/aardappel/procrastitracker/blob/9e51ff9eae7a0589674f1a48633269b78c3bdd7c/PT/file_format.txt#L4), that are compressed with `zlib`. I use the word "unfortunate" because I've never worked with `zlib`, and it turned out to be an incredibly difficult challenge. It seems that in order to process ProcrastiTracker's database file, one needs to *build* zlib from source, then write some utility script in C/C++, then compile that script, then -- theoretically -- the output will be some readable data.

But my problem is:

- I don't know C or C++
- I've tried building `zlib` on my windows machine using tutorials I found on YouTube, but unsuccessfully.

---

**My bottom line** here:
can anyone here advise on *how* to approach this task? Could it be pretty simple but I've over-complicated this? Otherwise, if you think that this seems too involving for a non-C-programmer, please say so.

Of note, I've tried [commenting on an issue](https://github.com/aardappel/procrastitracker/issues/77#issuecomment-922449299) in the Github repository of the program, to get some help from the developer. Didn't get me too far.

Comment: zlib isn't your problem. The data format is. You could use a hex editor to read some of the data, but it's not practical. You'd have to program your own reader.

Comment: @DanielB, thanks. So your comment implies what I fear of. Programming a reader seems beyond my set of skills :/

Comment: After reading the source code, @DanielB is ***exactly*** right.  The guy made his own database format.  ***I am really sorry if I wasted your time***.  My hunches are *usually* correct but not this time.  This is one of the things that sucks about proprietary formats but he did it for speed and size so it made sense.

Comment: Also.. I *do* have one other idea.  If you can figure out how to compile his source, adding a hack for forcing the database to be exported each time it is written to disk should be trivial.  You would probably hack line 96 of "day.h" and add a line to the function that does an `exporthtml("path of your choice here");`.  That will force the export each time the database gets saved to disk.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas, no worries. I appreciate the willingness and time invested in helping others. As I wrote in the post above, compiling the program from source is beyond my skills, and I've spent too many hours chasing software compiling solutions in which I don't even understand what I'm doing. So all in all, I'm giving my hopes to the point-and-click automation idea, which feels hacky and sloppy but is better than nothing.